# SQL order by repetitive sequence

Tags: sql

I have a query running in Oracle 11g:

```
SELECT id, sequence FROM objects WHERE parent=56;

Id.     Sequence
A           1
B           1
C           1
D           2
E           2
F           3
```

I would like the output to be grouped in a way that if a sequence Id already exists to move the new result to a new grouping at end

```
Id.        Sequence
A           1
D           2
F           3
B           1
E           2
C           1
```

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using.

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Sorry, first time posting via mobile!

Comment: I'm dealing with a database only through views I was given. The object has groups of children under it. I would have treated them all as one, and managed via one set of sequences, but that's not how they have it, and to make it worse same child (types) can be found under different "groups" of sequences. I am trying to get them ordered in groups by repeating sequences.

Comment: You may need to add more examples

Comment: That is it. That is literally the output I get from the view (less a few name columns)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to point out that you can put the `row_number()` in the `order by`:

```
select id, sequence
from objects
where parent = 56
order by row_number() over (partition by sequence order by id),
         sequence;
```

Comment: Thank you. I've learnt something new! I've not used Partition By before.

Answer (score 1):

If your dbms supports window functions, compute the row_number and use it for ordering.

```
SELECT id,Sequence
FROM (
SELECT id, Sequence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Sequence ORDER BY Id) as RN
FROM objects 
WHERE parent=56
) T
ORDER BY RN,Id
```